# GLM cuda error on constructor call

Tags: c++, cuda, glm-math

**Solved**

I'm trying to create a CUDA program that uses the GLM math library. 
I have a class/struct for a camera and a ray defined as:

```
class Camera
{
public:
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 lookat;
    vec3 up;
    float fov;

    Camera(vec3& p, vec3& la, vec3& u, float f) : pos(p), lookat(la), up(u), fov(f) {}
    Camera() : pos(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)), lookat(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), up(vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)), fov(60.0f*0.0174532925f) {}
};

typedef struct Ray
{
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 dir;
    __device__ __host__ Ray(vec3& p, vec3& d) : pos(p), dir(d) {}
    __device__ __host__ Ray() {}
} Ray;
```

The problem comes when I try to create a function that uses the camera and ray like this:

```
__device__ __host__ void calculateRay(int x, int y, int width, int height, Camera& camera)
{
float xoff = (x + 0.5f) / width;
float yoff = ((height - y) + 0.5f) / height;

vec3 dir = normalize(camera.lookat);
vec3 right = normalize(cross(dir, camera.up)) * (xoff - 0.5f);
vec3 down = -camera.up * (yoff - 0.5f);
dir += down + right;
vec3 rayDir = normalize(dir);

Ray ray(camera.pos, rayDir); //Error here

/*
Ray ray;
ray.pos.x = camera.pos.x;
ray.pos.y = camera.pos.y;
ray.pos.z = camera.pos.z;

ray.dir.x = rayDir.x;
ray.dir.y = rayDir.y;
ray.dir.z = rayDir.z;
*/
}
```

If I comment out the line "Ray ray(camera.pos, rayDir);" it compiles fine. It also compiles if I comment that out and uncomment the section below it.

The error the compiler gives is

```
error MSB3721: The command ""F:\dev\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe" 
-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_52,compute_50\" --use-local-env 
--cl-version 2013 -ccbin "F:\programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"  
-IG:\old\things\include\glm -IF:\dev\CUDA\include -IF:\dev\CUDA\include  
-G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile 
-cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler 
"/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj 
"C:\Users\a\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RayTracer\kernel.cu""
 exited with code 255.
```

Though I can't seem to find anything on what causes error code 255

Edit: Solved - Turns out it was caused by a bug in GLM, going back to version 9.6.2 fixes the problem.

Comment: please post a [mcve]; which GLM version, which CUDA version are you using?

Comment: @m.s. Thanks for the reply, looking up the GLM version made me think to try an older version and that solved the problem.

Comment: you might consider reporting a bug against either GLM or CUDA, depending on which one is responsible; of course that would require a [mcve] as well

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the customary method to indicate that a question is "Solved" is not to mark it "Solved" in the question text, but to provide an answer.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug in GLM, going back to version 9.6.2 fixed the problem for me. It should also be fixed in the newest release (9.7.1 at this time.)